# Change BooleanField value based on ForeignKey's BooleanField

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, django-forms

Is there a way to change the BooleanField of a model based on a change in the BooleanField of a ForeignKey Model it's linked to? For instance:

In models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ...
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...


class Task(models.Model):
    ...
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
```

If the user submits a form changing project.complete = True, is there a way I can automatically have all tasks connected to that project have task.complete = True?

I have tried overriding the form_valid function in my views.py for when the project.complete value is changed:

```
class ProjectCompleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Project
    fields = []

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.complete = not form.instance.complete
        tasks = form.instance.task_set.all()
        for task in tasks:
            task.complete = True
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Which didn't change the task.complete value as it's still False when I reload the page. I'm new to django, so if anyone has any insight on what I can do/how this works it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is task_set inside form_valid()

Comment: since form.instance is a project, task_set should be all of the tasks whose foreignkey is that project.

Comment: if you are going inside the loop then I think adding task.save() after task.complete=True will solve the issue. otherwise check whether you are getting the tasks or not

Comment: That completely solved it, thank you!